# i can't find my username on ubuntu

Tags: login, username

The last time I shut my computer down, it shut down normal.  But now it won't let me back on.  When it came to the first screen I pushed shift down, got onto the recovery mode and then onto to the root menu.  I tried what I thought was my username but it didn't work.  I typed in ls /home/ and what comes up is this: ne

what does this mean and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your username is ne, but I suggest you to try to come back to recovery mode and then from menu try fsck and after that update grub. Then try to reboot (to reboot enter in the room entry menu and from there type "reboot". Or from the recovery menu choice resume.